# How to connect a Camel route to a REST Service to receive an event-stream

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

Within a Camel route I need to connect to a service with a HTTP GET request and leave the connection open to receive events.
The Camel connection never receives events from the service.

I can use Postman to perform this operation successfully:[successful Postman connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOr61.png), so I know the service is running as expected.

My Camel Route calls the service endpoint as a GET with the same parameters used in Postman in the header of this call:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.GET))
.setHeader("Connection", simple("keep-alive"))
.setHeader("Accept", simple("text/event-stream"))
.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", simple("gzip, deflate, br"))
.setHeader("Postman-Token", simple("6ec7dfb3-6a4e-46ad-9f29-329a854f2649"))
.to("http://localhost:5000/events")
```

I know the service receives this call and creates event messages to send back, but they're never received by the Camel route. Also, a Postman connection that's made at the same time as the Camel connection does receive the event messages.

**Q**) What is the correct way to configure a Camel route to receive service events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OkHttpClient** can be used with a **RealEventSource** and a custom **EventSourceListener** to receive server side events.

Steps:

1. create a custom *Listener* class that extends *EventSourceListener* and has methods for handling events from the *RealEventSource*.

- onEvent() processes the server-side-event data received from the *Service*
- onOpen(), onClose(), onFailure() may also be useful

2. create a *Client* class that instantiates your *Listener*

- creates the OkHttpClient
- creates the Request to send to the *Service*
- creates a RealEventSource(Request, *Listener*)
- calls realEventSource.connect(okHttpClient);

3. create a *AccessToken* class for the values needed to access your *Service*
4. in the camel Route class instantiate the *Client*

- *Client* myClient = new Client();

5. in *Route*.configure() call

   .process(new Processor() {
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   myClient.Connect();
   }
   })

References:
[OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp)
[realeventsource](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=6c5b79d125a4bc87JmltdHM9MTY5MjkyMTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0xNmVlMzBlOS05MjU2LTYzNGMtMTQ5Yy0yMjIxOTM3YTYyN2MmaW5zaWQ9NTIwOQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=16ee30e9-9256-634c-149c-2221937a627c&psq=realeventsource%20listen%20for%20events&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmFlbGR1bmcuY29tL2phdmEtb2todHRwLWV2ZW50cw&ntb=1)